# How to make python script update in realtime (run continuously)

Tags: python-3.x, auto-update

Hello I am a beginner in python and I just learned the fundamentals and basics of programming in python. I wanted to make this program that will notify me when my class ends, however, once I run my program it only executes it once

When I loop it, it does not continuously access my date and time (instead it takes the time from when the code is executed). Any suggestion on how to resolve this problem?

```
import win10toast

import datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()

while (1):
    def Period_A():
        if currentDT.hour == 7 and currentDT.minute == 30:
            toaster.show_toast('Shedule Reminder', 'It is Period A time!', duration=10)
```

I wanted the code to run in the background and update the value of the date and time continuously so that the notification will appear on the desired time not the time when the code is executed ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()` is only called once throughout the whole program, and therefore stays constant to approximately the time you ran the script.

Since you're want to continuously check the time to compare it to a set time, you'll have to move that line to inside the loop.

Secondly, you define a function `Period_A` in the loop, which by itself does nothing because you don't call the function. If you don't need the abstraction a function gives you, there is no point in making one just to call it once.

```py
import datetime
import win10toast

toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()

while 1:
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

    if currentDT.hour == 7 and currentDT.minute == 30:
        toaster.show_toast('Shedule Reminder', 'It is Period A time!', duration=10)
```